# Does Android Studio's emulator support install, debug and testing of VR apps?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cardboard, google-vr

Specifically, apps written for cardboard using the Google VR sdk. I am working on such an app, and the system images provided by Google appear to be incompatible with their Cardboard and Google VR Services apps. I've searched the web, the Google Android and Android Studio documentation, and this site and can find no hint of (1) why they aren't compatible (presumably some required libraries are missing from the images) nor (2) how to fix it.

I'm running Android Studio 3.3 with version 28 of the build tools under Windows 10 with an Intel CPU. The error I actually get (from the Play Store) when selecting either of the apps is "Your device isn't compatible with this version."

The virtual Android device I've tried that seems most likely it should work for this is the stock Nexus 5 with Playstore for Intel x86 image, set up with 4096Mb internal storage, 512Mb SD card, and 1536 Mb RAM, and orientation sensors and GPU enabled.  I'm copying the parameters for it below.

> Name: Nexus_5_API_26_Play
>
> CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)
>
> Path: C:\Users\Chris Phelan.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_26_Play.avd
>
> Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 26)
>
> Skin: nexus_5
>
> SD Card: 512M
>
> fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:
>
> runtime.network.speed: full
>
> hw.accelerometer: yes
>
> hw.device.name: Nexus 5
>
> hw.lcd.width: 1080
>
> hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
>
> image.androidVersion.api: 26
>
> tag.id: google_apis_playstore
>
> hw.mainKeys: no
>
> hw.camera.front: emulated
>
> avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 26 Play
>
> hw.gpu.mode: auto
>
> hw.ramSize: 1536
>
> PlayStore.enabled: true
>
> fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
>
> hw.cpu.ncore: 4
>
> hw.keyboard: yes
>
> hw.sensors.proximity: yes
>
> hw.dPad: no
>
> hw.lcd.height: 1920
>
> vm.heapSize: 128
>
> skin.dynamic: yes
>
> hw.device.manufacturer: Google
>
> hw.gps: yes
>
> hw.audioInput: yes
>
> image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-26\google_apis_playstore\x86\
>
> showDeviceFrame: yes
>
> hw.camera.back: virtualscene
>
> AvdId: Nexus_5_API_26_Play
>
> hw.lcd.density: 480
>
> hw.arc: false
>
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:8559425ef53165ae4219cebb3e86e052
>
> fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
>
> fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
>
> hw.trackBall: no
>
> hw.battery: yes
>
> hw.sdCard: yes
>
> tag.display: Google Play
>
> runtime.network.latency: none
>
> disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
>
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>
> hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it's orientation to landscape and use manual rotation to change device angle.
You can find this capability in emulator settings

P.S:All configurations seem correct :)

Comment: Thanks! It seems to run without those apps installed, anyway. Still has problems, but those may be the subject of a different question. I am beginning to suspect I'll need a third-party emulator to do this without a lot of pain.